# Что не так с моим droppable методом?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Добрый день. Делаю клиентские шахматы на js без AI что бы начать понимать хоть что-то в архитектуре приложений.
Использую jQueryUI.

Задача №1 - научить пешку ходить вперед и все.

Проблема: пешка перемещается вперед, по вертикали B шах. поля, но **пройденные** поля становятся доступными как для хода назад, так и в дальнейшем для хода вперед . Ликвидация класса ui-droppable, как через {addClass: false}, так и вручную (removeClass для родителя - поля доски) не помогла. Даже при его отсутствии пройденные поля доступны для перетаскивания назад и вперед.

Тоесть правило *могу ходить вперед на одну клетку* срабатывает один раз для каждого поля, а потом отменяется. Не понимаю что на это влияет.

Спасибо.

```
var pawn = new Pawn('P'); //Конструктор не прилагаю, там ничего необычного

$(".sqB,.sqW").eq(49).append(pawn.img); //Вставка одной пешки на поле В2 шах. доски
$("img").attr("id", pawn.id); //Установка id для DOM-элемента пешки 


var allowID = ""; //id разрешенного для перетаскивания поля доски 
$("#"+pawn.id).mouseenter (function () {

    var $startPos = $(this).parent().attr("id");//id поля где пешка находится(В2)

    if (pawn.charFEN == 'P') allowID = "#"+ $startPos.split('')[0] + (+$startPos.split('')[1]+1);//id следующего поля(В3) 

    $(this).draggable ({revert:'invalid'});

    $(allowID).droppable({drop: function (e,ui) { // центрирование картинки пешки в поле
                            var cut = $(ui.draggable).detach();
                            $(this).append(cut.css({'top':'0','left':'0'}));
                        }});
});
```